# IE8 slice call issue - Array.prototype.slice - 'this' is not a Javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer-8, call, slice

This is a bit more complex issue than what was asked before, tried to use the responses given before but it just won't work.

This is the code

```
(function () {
    function init() {
        var speed = 330,
            easing = mina.backout;

       [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.grid > a')).forEach(function (el) {
            var s = Snap(el.querySelector('svg')), path = s.select('path'),
                pathConfig = {
                    from: path.attr('d'),
                    to: el.getAttribute('data-path-hover')
                };

            el.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
                path.animate({ 'path': pathConfig.to }, speed, easing);
            });

            el.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
                path.animate({ 'path': pathConfig.from }, speed, easing);
            });
        });
    }

    init();

})();
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('.grid > a') )`

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work bencripps. It still throws out the same error. Take a look at this screenshot. http://www.webpagescreenshot.info/i3/53fcb7f1d10883-60451702

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: jsfiddle won't be enough. Check it out here [link](http://test.pxlworld.ro/steve) in the js/jquery-func.js. Check it in IE 8 or IE 8 mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the selector (`'.grid > a'`) is CSS2 compliant, this should work just fine. Because `querySelectorAll` [only supports css2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll#Browser_compatibility) selectors in IE8.

Moreover you don't need to call the slice method and can just use the for each directly like this

```
   [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.grid > a'), function (el) {
        var s = Snap(el.querySelector('svg')), path = s.select('path'),
            pathConfig = {
                from: path.attr('d'),
                to: el.getAttribute('data-path-hover')
            };

        el.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
            path.animate({ 'path': pathConfig.to }, speed, easing);
        });

        el.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
            path.animate({ 'path': pathConfig.from }, speed, easing);
        });
    });
```

UPDATE - `[].forEach` is [compatible with >= IE9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Browser_compatibility)

```
var nodeArray = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.grid > a'));

for (var i = 0; i < nodeArray.length; i++) {
    var el = nodeArray[i];
    var s = Snap(el.querySelector('svg')),
        path = s.select('path'),
        pathConfig = {
            from: path.attr('d'),
            to: el.getAttribute('data-path-hover')
        };

    el.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
        path.animate({
            'path': pathConfig.to
        }, speed, easing);
    });

    el.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
        path.animate({
            'path': pathConfig.from
        }, speed, easing);
    });
}
```

Comment: this creates a different error. "unable to get property 'call' of undefined or null reference' [link](http://www.webpagescreenshot.info/img/54041349db4785-64962716)

Comment: oops, sorry I forgot to mention that `forEach` was added in IE9, see my update

Comment: thanks for the continued help, but this updated code brings back the original error at the first line where it says `var nodeArray = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.grid > a'));` see the original link => [link](http://test.pxlworld.ro/steve)